# How to skip ending with readdlm?

Tags: julia, readdlm

I got some data and I don't want the last 5 lines which are some info.

I already tried to read it all and then cut but I can't cause the data are (61,9) while the ending is some any type (5,1) and it is throwing an error. 
I tried with dims but it continue to read after the specified dimensions.

Is there any other solutions than to read line per line ?

Thank you !!!

Comment: You can use CSV.jl which has appropriate options to handle this case. See https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/latest/#Reading-Chunks-1.

Comment: Oh thank you so much ! I try that :)

Comment: Should make that an answer